# Pass current page URL on click to CF7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Hi I'm using CF7 Dynamic Text Extension.

I have a call back button that goes to a CF7 Form, but I need to know the URL that the click came from. Currently using the code below

`<?php echo '<a style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);color:#000000;" href="/call-back-request/ context='.urlencode(get_the_title($post->ID)) .'">Request Callback</a>'; ?>`

However there are titles that are the same, so I really need the URL to tell us exactly what the contact is related to.

Comment: Have you seen this? - https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/referrer-input-for-contact-form-7/

Comment: Isnt that what the [_url] shortcode does? It does on my website anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
get_the_title($post->ID)
```

Make it

```
get_permalink($post->ID)
```

Comment: That’s great, glad I could help :)